# abstract base class vs generic relations in django

Tags: mysql, django, database-design, django-models, abstract-class

What are the pros and cons of abstract base classes and generic relations using generic foreign keys in django?

Abstract base classes imply a single abstract class with child classes.  Here is an example:

```
class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['name']

class Student(CommonInfo):
    ...
    class Meta(CommonInfo.Meta):
        db_table = 'student_info'
```

Generic relations are entities that use generic foreign keys with an object id on a single table.  Here is an example:

```
class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    tag = models.SlugField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

What are situations and/or the criterion for when you should use one solution or the other?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman what do you think about this? Is one or the other a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I think the abstract base class paradigm is more consistent with natural relation database architecture.  Generic relations is more of hack and bypasses referential integrity.

Abstract base classes are the way to go.